# When are all split monomorphisms complemented?

Tags: ct.category-theory

In a category $\mathcal C$, let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y \rightarrow X$ such that $g \circ f = id_X$. Is there a general criterion on $\mathcal C$ such that the following holds: there is an object $Z$ such that $Y = X \sqcup Z$ (the coproduct of $X$ and $Z$)?

Thanks for any answer.

(retitled the question as per the comment below)

Comment: It's certainly true if C is abelian, but I guess you're looking for something a bit more interesting.  

Comment: As a terminological point, it is usual in category theory to say that a "split monomorphism" is one with a retract, whereas one which satisfies the conclusion of your question is "complemented."  So your question would be less confusing if it were titled "when are all split monomorphisms complemented?"

Comment: I retitled it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In the setting of the question, the composite $f\circ g$ is idempotent.  Thus one
hypothesis on $\mathcal C$ that will guarantee the existence of the desired splittings is
that $\mathcal C$ be Karoubian, or (same concept, alternative name) [pseudo-abelian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-abelian_category), which is to say: $\mathcal C$ is pre-additive (the Hom-sets are abelian groups) and all idempotents have kernels (and hence cokernels).

Answer (score 0):

This is true in boolean categories (extensive + terminal object + (T : 1 → 1 + 1) is subobject classifier), but for *any* monic, not just split monics. There's quite a nice and easy read on extensive categories from 93:

Carboni et al. Introduction to extensive and distributive categories. Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra (1993) vol. 84 pp. 145-158

However, modulo axiom of choice, all monics in Set split, and I suspect this could be true for any boolean category.

Comment: Even in Set, not all monics split: consider any function from an empty set to a nonempty one.  (-:

Comment: Also, I think the more usual definition of "Boolean category" includes regularity but not extensivity: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Boolean%20category

Comment: That sneaky empty set. :)